# Can i separate a php variable?

Tags: php, html, string, variables

okay so lets say  $word = abcdefg@hijk.lmn

can i make a new variable only everything upto the "@"

and another everything after?

( I.E.  $one = abcdefg   &   $two = hijk.lmn )

thanks alot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `explode`.

```
$word = 'abcdefg@hijk.lmn';
$my_array = explode('@', $word);
echo $my_array[0]; // prints "abcdefg"
echo $my_array[1]; // prints "hijk.lmn"
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: And if you want to assign the parts to variables rather than an array, use `list($one, $two) = explode('@', $word);`

Comment: I think i love you guys. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
list($one, $two) = split("@", $word);
```

Comment: `split` is deprecated as of 5.3. It's also overkill (uses a regex where one is not needed).